# How to transform this code ob block to a function?

Tags: c#, json, list

I use the below block of code a lot in my code. I want to put it in a function, but it's not working.

```
using (StreamReader streamReader = new StreamReader(path, true))
                {
                    string json = streamReader.ReadToEnd();
                    userdata = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<User>>(json);
                    streamReader.Close();
                }


//List<User> userdata = new List<User>();//this is a comment
```

I am deserializing a json file that contain an array of objects.

this is the function that I write.

```
 static void deserializeuser(List<dynamic> @params, string y)
    {
        using (StreamReader streamReader = new StreamReader(y, true))
        {
            string json = streamReader.ReadToEnd();
            @params = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<dynamic>>(json);
            streamReader.Close();
        }

    }
```

this function doesn't show errors but I don't know how to call it.

Comment: You tried? Can you show what have you tried?

Comment: "But the code is not working" is not very specific. Can you please [edit] your question to let us know what the expected result is and how your code fails to achieve it? [Reading this](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) may be useful

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
    public List<T> GetFromPath<T>(string path)
    {
        List<T> ret = null;
        try
        {
            using (StreamReader streamReader = new StreamReader(path, true))
            {
                string json = streamReader.ReadToEnd();
                ret = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<T>>(json);
                streamReader.Close();
            }
        }
        catch(Exception ex)
        {
            // Log here
            throw;
        }
        return ret;
    }
```

or

```
    public List<T> GetFromPath<T>(string path)
    {
        List<T> ret = null;
        try
        {
            if(File.Exists(path))
                ret = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<T>>(File.ReadAllText(path));
        }
        catch(Exception ex)
        {
            // Log here
            throw;
        }
        return ret;
    }
```

**Edit**

Made it a generic call, use

```
List<User> list = GetFromPath<User>("somepath");
```

Answer (score 0):

This should work:

```
private static List<T> DeserializeList<T>(string path)
{
    List<T> result = null;

    using (var streamReader = new StreamReader(path, true))
    {
        string json = streamReader.ReadToEnd();
        result = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<T>>(json);
        streamReader.Close();
    }

    return result;
 }
```

...

```
List<User> userdata = DeserializeList<User>(path);
```

Answer (score 0):

An even more generic flavor of your function

```
private static T GetTypedDataFromFile<T>(string path)
{
    T result = null;
    // I prefer C# 8.0 using syntax here.
    // If your C# version is older, please revert to original with brackets
    using var streamReader = new StreamReader(path, true);
    
    string json = streamReader.ReadToEnd();
    result = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<T>(json);
    streamReader.Close();
    
    return result;
 }
```

And call by

```
List<User> users = DeserializeList<List<User>>(path);
```